# How to get the value of a foreign key

Tags: python, django

two classes in `models.py`:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    book_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    storage_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_id

class Delivery(models.Model):
    book_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    storage_id = models.ForeignKey('Purchase', editable=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_id
```

I use the following code to get the value of `storage_id` in Delivery after the form is saved:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Delivery)
def removeProducts(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(instance.storage_id)
```

The problem is, what I get is not `Delivery.storage_id`, it is `Purchase.book_id`. How to get the value of `Delivery.storage_id` without changing the `__str__` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't call your ForeignKey fields `foo_id`. It's not an ID, it's the actual object. I'm also not sure why the field is called `storage` but the model it links to is `Purchase`. It should be:

```
purchase = models.ForeignKey('Purchase', editable=True)
```

Now we have eliminated the confusion between what's an object and what's a field, we can simply follow the relationship:

```
print(instance.purchase.storage_id)
```